# How to downgrade R version in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: r

I installed R version 3.4.4-1ubuntu1 How do I downgrade to 3.2.2?
I tried this solution but it didn't work
sudo apt-get remove r-base-core
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get install r-base-core=3.2.2